# Finding an invariant subspace of a linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:

> > Let $ T: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ defined by a rotation of 30 degrees about the vector $a = (1,2,3) $; Find an invariant subspace of $T$. Is $T$ a bijection?

What I first did was find the matrix representation of T by using the equation about an unit vector.

$a = (1,2,3)$ and the corresponding unit vector is $\frac1{\sqrt14} \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

The formula for the rotation matrix around an unit vector is:

$$Q = (cos\Theta)I + (1-cos\theta) \begin{bmatrix} a_1^2 & a_1a_2 & a_1a_3\\ a_1a_2&a_2^2&a_2a_3\\ a_1a_3&a_2a_3&a_3^2 \end{bmatrix} - sin\theta  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a_3 & -a_2\\ -a_3&0&a_1\\ a_2&-a_1&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using $\theta = 30,  a_1=\frac1{\sqrt14},  a_2=\frac2{\sqrt14}, a_3=\frac3{\sqrt14}$

I got 
$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt3}2  & 0&0 \\ 0&\frac{\sqrt3}2&0\\ 0&0&\frac{\sqrt3}2  \end{bmatrix} + \frac{2-\sqrt3}{2\sqrt14} \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\2&4&6\\3&6&9\end{bmatrix} - \frac1{2\sqrt14} \begin{bmatrix} 0&3&-2\\-3&0&1\\2&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

From here, how would I find all the invariant subspaces of $T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T$ is a rotation around a vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then the subspace generated by that vector is invariant. There are no other one dimensional invariant subspaces, can you find a two dimensional one? I suggest thinking about this geometrically first, and then diving into computations.

Comment: My professor does want us to find an invariant subspace other than the 0 subspace and the $\mathbb{R}^3$. So would the invariant subspace be the subspace generated by that vector? Would that mean all the linear combinations of that vector with a scalar?

Comment: The subspace $W $generated by the vector $(1,2,3)$ is an invariant subspace, yes. And by the definition of a subspace generated by a vector, $W = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : (x,y,z) = \alpha (1,2,3), \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \}$, so yes, scalar multiples of the vector.

Comment: What would be an explanation of this? Does the degree of rotation matter in this case or did he just put it there for no reason? He did hint that $T(v)$ = (the vector you get by rotating $v$ 30 degrees counterclockwise about $a = (1,2,3)$.

Comment: Perhaps he wanted you to find all the invariant subspaces of $T$? In that case, the degree of rotation becomes relevant. Or perhaps he wants you to prove things using a matrix representation of your transformation, for which you would need this information. As for the explanation, what happens to a vector if you rotate it about itself?

Comment: To find all the invariant subspaces of T, should I find the eigenspaces of the Q matrix?

Comment: If you rotate a vector about itself, wouldn't it just stay on itself?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Can you see that this also happens to multiples of this vector? Why?

Comment: The multiples of the vector would be the same vector with longer length and so the rotation would still make it on itself. So that proves that $T(v) \in V$ for every $v \in V$! How would I know if this is a bijection? The transformation will not be the same for the vectors that are in different lengths proving injectivity. But how would I prove surjectivity?

Comment: Actually, the usual definition of a rotation implies that lengths don't change, but you are right that $T(v) \in   V$. As for bijectivity, perhaps you have seen in class that if $det(A) = 0$ for a matrix, then it represents an invertible (so, bijective) linear transformation.